# Define an environment with mdframed and set default text at it's beginning

Tags: hyperref, mdframed

I am working on a script for my students, where they can read explanations and exercises.

Hence I have defined an environment with package mdframed to use colored boxes, that float with page breaks like this:

```
\newmdtheoremenv[%
  backgroundcolor=black!7,
  linecolor=red,
  linewidth=1pt,
  ]{ex}{Excercise}
```

Now I want to set a Checkbox with hyperref, so the students can check off an exercise.

The checkbox is set with pakage marginnote at the left margin and it is working this way:

```
\begin{ex}
\marginnote{
\begin{Form}
    \CheckBox[width=.6cm]{~}
\end{Form}
}
\lipsum
\end{ex}
```

What I need is, that I can use `\begin{ex} ... \end{ex}` and the checkbox will be automaticly set. I don't want to set the box every time like above.

So I want something like this:

```
\newmdtheoremenv[%
  backgroundcolor=black!7,
  linecolor=red,
  linewidth=1pt,
  at every beginning do:
       \marginnote{
          \begin{Form}
              \CheckBox[width=.6cm]{~}
          \end{Form}
       }
  ]{ex}{Excercise}
```

To be precise, I want to define an environment that sets a text (or in my case a checkbox) at every beginning, with mdframed.

Is there a way?

Comment: Btw: Interesting wording "float with page breaks". If you had one that would be as interesting as finding the philosopher's stone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a solution I could come up with.

First of all, I define the new counter `exercise` that I will use later to number the boxes. Next I define a new environment that contains the style of the boxes, the way the title is set up and the checkboxes. To make the checkboxes individually 'tick-able' in the resulting pdf, they need a unique `name`. I therefore reused the counter I defined earlier.

**1. Continous numbering of exercises throughout document**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{exercise}
\newenvironment{exercise}
{\refstepcounter{exercise}%
\mdfsetup{%
backgroundcolor=black!7,
linecolor=red,
linewidth=1pt,
frametitle=Exercise~\theexercise%
\marginnote{%
\begin{Form}%
\CheckBox[width=.6cm,name=ex\theexercise]{~}%
\end{Form}%
}%
}%
\begin{mdframed}%
}%
{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
short example entry
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
\lipsum
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

**2. Numbering of exercises using current chapter (or section) number**

The above code numbers all exercises with continuing numbers throughout the entire document. If you prefer a numbering scheme like `Exercise 3.1` with `3` being the number of the current **chapter**, please refer to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{exercise}[chapter]
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@exercise}{\thechapter.}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{exercise}
{\refstepcounter{exercise}%
\mdfsetup{%
backgroundcolor=black!7,
linecolor=red,
linewidth=1pt,
frametitle=Aufgabe~\thechapter.\theexercise%
\marginnote{%
\begin{Form}%
\CheckBox[width=.6cm,name=ex\thechapter\theexercise]{~}%
\end{Form}%
}%
}%
\begin{mdframed}%
}%
{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter title}
\begin{exercise}
short example entry
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
\lipsum
\label{ex:Kirchhof}
\end{exercise}

\ref{ex:Kirchhof}
\end{document}
```

If you want the numbering scheme of your exercises to be 2.1 with 2 being the current **section**'s number, simply replace every occurence of `chapter` with `section`.

Comment: Thanx for this, works fine, but now i figured out, that the labels of the excercises doen't work. I used e.g. `\label{ex:Kirchhoff}` and then later `\ref{ex:Kirchhoff}`, but it's pointing at a complete different exercise or figure.

Comment: @Cauti: Thank you for drawing my attention at this. There was a small mistake in the code that I have corrected now. According to my tests, cross referencing exercises using the `\ref` command now works.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I use chapter instead of section and my Environment is called Aufgabe, but `\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@Aufgabe}{\thechapter.} \makeatother` doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Cauti: To clarify: Do you want `Aufgabe 1` or `Aufgabe 1.1` (with the first number being the number of the actual chapter)? In the first case, please make sure, that it says `\refstepcounter` instead of the wrong `\stepcounter` that I had used before.

Comment: @Cauti: I have extended my answer to include a full MWE that shows the latter numbering scheme (including the number of the current chapter).

Comment: Perfect! `\refstepcounter` was the answer (beside 42)

Answer (score 1):

The following solution uses the flexible `tcolorbox` package. I've also added the package `xsim` which is very flexible in creating exercises for students (even with points etc. if you'd like to extend that; you also have a solution environment at hand, if you need it).

There's also no problem with references, you can just use a label approach.

[image: part 1]

[image: part 2]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{exstyle/.style={colframe=red,colback=black!7,sharp corners=all,breakable,title after break={(Aufgabe \thechapter.\theaufgabe\ Fortsetzung)}}}

\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{solution/print=false}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{tcolorbox}{%
  \tcolorbox[exstyle,title = {\strut\GetExerciseName~\thechapter.\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}]
  \IfInsideSolutionF{%
     \marginnote{\vskip-3\baselineskip%
            \begin{Form}%
            \CheckBox[width=.6cm,name=ex\thechapter\theaufgabe]{~}%
            \end{Form}%
        }%
    }
}{\endtcolorbox}
\DeclareExerciseType{aufgabe}{
  exercise-env=aufgabe,
  solution-env=loesung,
  exercise-name={Aufgabe},
  solution-name={Lösung zu Aufgabe},
  exercise-template=tcolorbox,
  solution-template=tcolorbox,
  within=chapter,
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@aufgabe}{\thechapter.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter title}
\begin{aufgabe}\label{test}
short example entry
\end{aufgabe}
\begin{loesung}
a test
\end{loesung}
\ref{test}
\begin{aufgabe}\label{tetest}
\lipsum
\label{ex:Kirchhof}
\end{aufgabe}
\begin{loesung}
a test
\end{loesung}
\ref{ex:Kirchhof}

\printsolutions[headings=false]
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) for the more powerful `tcolorbox` usage ;-) The TeX Force is Strong In You ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, using `tcolorbox` is always right, as is answering `42`, but as an answer with `42` would probably be low-quality here I have to go the tcolorbox way ;)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer On a more serious note: I've created a little counter mess (see those `\the...`).

Comment: `\let\tcolorbox42 ;-) (o.k. not fully correct :D)

Comment: Do you mean `\renewcommand{\p@aufgabe}{\thechapter.}`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer And the `\thechapter.\theaufgabe` within the definition of `exstyle` and `\thechapter.\GetExerciseProperty{counter}`...

Comment: I am not into `xsim` yet, so I can't say this is a bad or a good setup. Apparently clemens has used an interface/approach quite similar to mine (still unpublished) question/answer package. It seems the way to go here how you had managed it

Comment: Looks good, I will give it a try.